# several site collection add into "Readonly" mode using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, powershell-script

We have 100+ site collections on csv file and we need to mark all sites into "Read Only" mode access based on csv file using powershell script. Anyone suggestion highly appreciate. we am trying below script but facing some issue. SharePoint 2013 environment

---

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$SitesColl = import-csv "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\test.csv"
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
  Set-SPSite -Identity "$site.Url" -LockState "ReadOnly"
 }
```

---

```
Error :Set-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
@{Url=http://sharepoint.test.com/sites/xx}.Url.
At C:\Users\xxxxxxx\script.ps1:5 char:3
+   Set-SPSite -Identity "$site.Url" -LockState "ReadOnly"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletSetSite:
   SPCmdletSetSite) [Set-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetSite
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested Successfully with the followings:

1. CSV file Sample:

```
Url
"http://myServer.com/sites/ABC/"
"http://myServer.com/sites/XYZ/"
"http://myServer.com/sites/VCS/"
"http://myServer.com/sites/BVC/"
```

2. PS Script

```
Cls

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$SitesColl = import-csv "C:\Temp\2020\SiteCollections.csv"


# Set Read Only
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
   
   Write-Host "Set Readonly:" $Site.Url
   
   Set-SPSite -Identity $Site.Url -LockState "ReadOnly"   
   #Set-SPSite -Identity $Site.Url -LockState "Unlock" 
}


# Check ReadOnly Status
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
   $Mysite=Get-SPSite -Identity $Site.Url  

   Write-Host "ReadOnly Status:" $MySite.ReadOnly
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matiur. Incase, if we have subsites means, is there any change on script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotation mark around `$site.Url`.

Use this, it should work for you:

```
Set-SPSite -Identity $site.Url -LockState "ReadOnly"
```

Comment: removed quotation, the same issue coming. If run only command it working. But if I want to fetch data from CSV and run command, it's not working. Please share if any alternate code. Our requirement is simple. PowerShell script needs to fetch data from csv files and list of site collections needs to lock as "Read-only" mode.

Comment: Once a site collection is set to read-only, sub-sites are automatically set to read only. There's no command to separately set sub-sites read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize `s` in `$site`

Correct code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$SitesColl = import-csv "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\test.csv"
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
  Set-SPSite -Identity $Site.Url -LockState "ReadOnly"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raf, Incase if we have subsites means what we need to do?